# Serializing vs not Serializing Protobuf object in Spring REST call

Tags: java, spring, protocol-buffers

Currently I am creating some intra-service calls among microservices. Opting to leverage google's protobuf, I am using it in unison with Spring Boot Rest APIs. And I am presented with two options.

First: Serializing the protobuf objects. It is possible to serialize protobuf objects in the REST request and have the receiving end deserialize it and perform whatever it needs, then serialize a protobuf response for the initial caller. This involves a flow of serializing, deserializing, and vice versa.

Second: Sending the protobuf object as is. It seems like a REST API is able to accept x-protobuf requests. I am wondering if this has any significant drawbacks in terms of speed?

Currently, I am employing the latter, I was wondering if anyone else who has tried this prefers one over the other?

Comment: Can you explain in other words exactly what you mean by _serializing_ objects?

Comment: The only understanding I have of your two approaches is that "First" sends the messages as JSON and "Second" sends the message as protobuf's binary format. The proto binary format will usually be smaller than the JSON equivalent. Peers will **always** need to serialize|deserialize (marshall|unmarshall) messages to convert between language-specific types and JSON or proto's binary format; you're not doing fewer transformations and you may be doing more.